# Django template multiple for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a tuple which holds multiple color and their codes:

```
color_list = (
    ('#CD5C5C', 'Indian Red'),
    ('#F08080', 'Light Coral'),
    ('#FA8072', 'Salmon'),
        ................
   )
```

and this is the model:

```
class ColorList(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(choices=color_list, max_length=10)

class Product(models.Model):
    color_list = models.ManyToManyField(ColorList)
```

view:

```
def product_edit(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product.objects.prefetch_related('color_list'), pk=pk)
    context = {'product': product,'color_list': color_list}
    return render(request, 'admin/product/product_edit.html', context)
```

Now I want to edit previously saved  data in template using a form:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label><strong>Color List</strong></label>
      <select name="color_list" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple  data-live-search="true" >
          {% for key, value in color_list %}
                {% for pro_color in product.color_list.all %}
                     <option value="{{ key }}" {% if pro_color.color == key %} selected {% endif %}>
                       {{ value }}
                      </option>
                 {% endfor %}
           {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>
```

I want to show previously selected color with other color options, but using this template code, it generating multiple duplicate `<options>`. So the problem is how can I use multiple for loop in template with preselected color `<options>` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your colors are duplicating is because you nested two loops unnecessarily to get the key/value pairs. You can use `.get_FOO_display()` instead.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label><strong>Color List</strong></label>
      <select name="color_list" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple  data-live-search="true" >
                {% for pro_color in product.color_list.all %}
                     <option value="{{ pro_color.get_color_display }}" {% if pro_color.color == color_list.color %} selected {% endif %}>
                       {{ pro_color.color }}
                      </option>
                 {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>
```

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Answer (score 0):

For Edit Related Issues, Refer Template of Django Admin > Edit User

Probable url will be: `http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/{id}/change/`

Here They Have Permissions column which is `Select Many` and it ofcause retains its value on refresh too.